# .htaccess url: rewrite is not working at local host Xampp

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, localhost

My current url is

```
http://localhost/www.zeeshan.com/user.php?name=zeeshan06
```

I want to display my url as

```
http://localhost/www.zeeshan.com/user/zeeshan06
```

I use the following code but it not working

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)user.php?name=$1 [R]
```

Please help me to solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: The last rule you mixed up the source and target patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place this `.htaccess` inside the folder `www.zeeshan.com`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /www.zeeshan.com/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)$ user.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

And access the URL:

```
http://localhost/www.zeeshan.com/user/zeeshan06
```

It should lead you to:

```
http://localhost/www.zeeshan.com/user.php?name=zeeshan06
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //   http://localhost/Milan_Practice/Milan_Mvc/routing.php?name=about

RewriteEngine On    

Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ /Milan_Practice/Milan_Mvc/routing\.php\?name=([^&]+)

RewriteRule ^ /Milan_Practice/Milan_Mvc/routing/%2/%3?%4 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?Milan_Practice/Milan_Mvc/routing/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /Milan_Practice/Milan_Mvc/routing.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Above code is working & will convert query string to Url Rewriting,May be incase problem occurs,then it will on line 10